# install tesseract in centos7.3 ? when use ./configure ,now have a error,and how to solove?

Tags: node.js, linux

I am getting this error:

```
./configure: line 4193: syntax error near unexpected token `-mavx,'
./configure: line 4193: `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG(-mavx, avx=true, avx=false)'
```

I have Leptonica installed.

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

1) Install autoconf-archive
2) run ./autogen.sh after the installation of autoconf-archive